# ¿Como convertir string a char*?

Tags: c++, array, string, punteros

quería preguntar sobre como convertir un string a un char*, el caso es el expuesto a continuación, donde tengo un string definido y quiero nombrar a la variable x usando .setName(), pero este recibe un char*, por lo que no puedo simplemente ubicar al string nombresvariables como argumento del .setName()(el ciclo for era la idea). Alguna idea sobre como poder meter como argumento un string en .setName()? o quizá no definirlo como string?

```
    IloNumVarArray x;
    string nombresvariables[12] = {"x11","x21","x31","x41","x12","x22","x32","x42","x13","x23","x33","x43"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {      
    x[i].setName(); //numero de variables
    }

    //x[0].setName("x11"); evitar tener que hacer esto
    //x[1].setName("x21");
    //x[2].setName("x31");
    //x[3].setName("x41");
    //x[4].setName("x12");
    //x[5].setName("x22");
    //x[6].setName("x32");
    //x[7].setName("x42");
    //x[8].setName("x13");
    //x[9].setName("x23");
    //x[10].setName("x33");
    //x[11].setName("x43");
```

Comment: ¿Puedes (por favor) compartir la definición de `x` y de su tipo?

Comment: El objeto string de c++ tiene el metodo `c_str()` el cual devuelve un char* con el contenido del string.

Comment: x[i].setName(nombresvariables[i].c_str()); esa era la solución, gracias Sacha

Comment: @Sacha ¿Y por qué no publicas una solución en vez de dejarlo como un comentario?

Comment: @Sacha te sugiero que escribas una respuesta para que se pueda marcar como solución. Cuando lo hagas avísame y borro mi respuesta

Comment: @eferion gracias por la amabilidad, la realidad es que lo publique como comentario proque pense que esa solucion podria hacer que se replantease la pregunta, buscando una solucion mas extensa. Ahora mismo publico la respuesta

Comment: @Sacha si tienes una solución al problema que se plantea en la pregunta, escribe una respuesta. Si tienes dudas entonces escribe vía comentarios, pero lo ideal sería que cada pregunta (bien planteada) tuviese al menos una respuesta válida

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` tiene un método `c_str` que te da acceso directo a su memoria interna... un puntero de tipo char:

```
char const* ptr = nombresvariables.c_str();
```

Con este método puedes hacer la llamada directa:

```
x[i].setName(nombresvariables[i].c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

La clase std::string tiene el método c_str() que te retorna un puntero al buffer de caracteres del string.

Tu código sería de la siguiente manera.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {      
          x[i].setName(nombresvariables[i].c_str()); //numero de variables
    }
```

Tienes que tener especialmente cuidado con este método, pues al retornarte un puntero a su buffer si el objeto se destruye te quedas con un puntero que apunta a una zona de memoria que ya no utilizas o se utiliza para otra cosa.

Un ejemplo de lo que no tendrías que hacer sería lo siguiente.

```
char *puntero = NULL;
if(una condicion ...){
    string unacadena = "hola";
    puntero = unacadena.c_str();
}

...
printf("%s", puntero);
```

Te mostraría basura, pues el ambito de unacadena esta dentro del if.

Para que no te ocurra eso puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
char *puntero = NULL;
if(una condicion ...){
    string unacadena = "hola";
    puntero = new char[unacadena.lentgh()];
    strcpy(puntero, unacadena.c_str());
}

...
if(puntero != NULL)
    delete puntero[];
```

Tienes información de la clase string en el enlace http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string

Answer (score 2):

La clase `string` posee un metodo llamado `c_str()`  el cual devuelve un char* con el contenido del string. De modo que podrias reescribir tu programa de la siguiente forma:

```
IloNumVarArray x;

string nombresvariables[12] = {"x11","x21","x31","x41","x12","x22","x32","x42","x13","x23","x33","x43"};

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {      
    x[i].setName(nombresvariables[i].c_str());
}
```